# django - Runpython function to turn charfield into foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I've been strugglin to relate a `csv` imported data model with a spatial data model based on a `CharField`.

I've created both models and now im trying to transfer the data from one field to a new one to be the `ForeignKey` field. I made a `Runpython` funtion to apply on the migration but it goives the an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'921-5'":
  "D2015ccccccc.rol_fk" must be a "D_Base_Roles" instance.
```

Here are the models:

```
class D_Base_Roles(models.Model):
    predio = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    dest = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    dir = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    rol = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=254)
    vlr_tot = models.FloatField()
    ub_x2 = models.FloatField()
    ub_y2 = models.FloatField()
    instrum = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    codzona = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    nomzona = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    geom = models.MultiPointField(srid=32719)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.rol)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural = "Roles"

class D2015ccccccc(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=80)
    nombre_archivo = models.CharField(max_length=180, blank=True, null=True)
    derechos = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    dir_calle = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    dir_numero = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_certificado = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_certificado = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_solicitud = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    rol_sii = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    zona_prc = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    ##NEW EMPTY FOREIGNKEY FIELD
    rol_fk = models.ForeignKey(D_Base_Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numero_certificado)

    class Meta:
         managed = True
         #db_table = 'domperm2015cip'
         verbose_name_plural = "2015 Certificados Informaciones Previas"
         ordering = ['numero_certificado']
```

The `Runpython` function:

```
def pop_rol(apps, schema_editor):
    roles = apps.get_model('b_dom_edificacion', 'D2015ccccccc')
    for r in roles.objects.all():
        rol = roles
        r.rol_fk = r.rol_sii
        r.save()
```

`D_Base_Roles.rol` values are all unique, and `921-5` is one of those values.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the line `rol = roles` supposed to do? You assign the model class `b_dom_edificacion.D2015ccccccc` to the variable `rol`, but never use it later

Comment: you're right, does nothing, i guess i left it there form a previous approach

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to assign an object, not a string. Change the line

```
r.rol_fk = r.rol_sii
```

to

```
r.rol_fk = D_Base_Roles.objects.get(rol=r.rol_sii)
```

Maybe adjust to whatever the correct field for looking up `D_Base_Roles` instances is.

Note: this will make a database query for every iteration of the `for`-loop

Comment: Thanks, I see now that in the case of a foreignkey it must point to an object, but now it gives me a "ValueError: Cannot assign "<D_Base_Roles: 921-5>": "D2015ccccccc.rol_fk" must be a "D_Base_Roles" instance", 921-5 is an instance, and i assignated the rol field as pk

Comment: That is strange... Have you tried importing the model outside of the forloop using `D_Base_Roles = apps.get_model('b_dom_edificacion', 'D_Base_Roles')` ?

Comment: yes, it gave a "no matching query" error, ..?, maybe rebuild a  fresh database?, I've been toying a lot with these one, lots of migration errors and fixes